# Javascript Delete A Specific Row

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to get a script to delete a table row.

```
var i = 1;

function addURL() {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute("id", "url_row_" + ++i);
    var td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    td.style.valign = 'middle';

    td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    var input = td.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
    input.name = 'url[]';
    input.type = 'text';
    input.size = '40'
    var node = document.getElementById('myTable').tBodies[0];
    node.insertBefore(tr, node.children[3]);

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", ""); 
    link.setAttribute("style", "text-decoration: none;");
    link.setAttribute("onClick", "removeURL('');return false;");
    td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    td=td.appendChild(link)
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('-'));
}

function removeURL(divNum) {
    var d = document.getElementById('myTable').tBodies[0];
    var olddiv = document.getElementById(divNum);
    d.removeChild(olddiv);
}
```

This can produce as many url_row_(number) text fields as I want. I just don't know how to delete those rows.

I know doing

```
link.setAttribute("onClick", "removeURL('url_row_2');return false;");
```

will delete url_row_2, but what can I put at url_row_2 that will grab whatever id that the row is or what is the correct code to do this?

Comment: "*grab whatever id that the row is*" - by what do you want to identify it if not by the id?

Comment: I want to identify it by the id, but I can't put url_row_2 because that will only delete that row. I need it to grab the id for each row the link "-" is in. If I create url_row_2, url_row_3, and url_row_4, a "-" will be beside them. When I click on "-", it should delete the row that the "-" I click on is in. If I click on "-" that is next to url_row_3, it will delete url_row_3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it that way, you would use string concatenation to concatenate `i` into the handler string to target the given `tr`.

```
link.setAttribute("onclick", "removeURL('url_row_" + i + "');return false;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `setAttribute` for event listeners. Have a look at the [Introduction to event handling at quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html), and especially on the [simple event registration model](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html). Also, you can just use the information from the event object to identify the row to remove:

```
function clickHandler(event) {
    var anchor = this; // == event.targetElement
    var tr = anchor.parentNode.parentNode;
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
    event.preventDefault(); // do not follow the href
}

function addURL() {
    …

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", "#"); 
    link.setAttribute("style", "text-decoration: none;");
    link.onclick = clickHandler;
    td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    td.appendChild(link)
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('-'));
}
```